# How to reference identical files on multiple nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, files

I have created two nodes that contain a File Upload.
Is it possible to reference files common to both nodes or do I have to create duplicates? I want to reduce the overhead of managing large number of uploaded files.

Comment: If this is going to be common, you might consider creating a content type to encapsulate the file and then reference that from your nodes in question here.

Comment: Have a look at this module: http://drupal.org/project/references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) suite which provides a media browser from which you can select existing files. Media also allows to add fields to your files to add additional meta data to them. The current UI in Media 7.x-1.x is unfortunately not what you could be, there are e.g. no filters in the media browser.

An alternative, as suggested in the comments, is to create a content type with just the uploaded file and then reference that node instead of the file. I'd say this is more the 6.x-like way to do this, but it does work as well...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) that allows you to upload, choose files on the server or add remote files to re-use files where ever they live... Handy.